# Error when adding custom revision in Hibernate envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

When I add custom revision entity, I start getting error:

```
2020-12-13 00:22:29.418 ERROR 80983 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4384acd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4384acd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry
```

MyRevision:

```
package ...;

import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@RevisionEntity(MyRevisionListener.class)
public class MyRevision extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
}
```

MyRevisionListener:

```
package ...;

// import de.xxxxx.carorderprocess.models.User;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;
// import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
// import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
// import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

// import java.util.Optional;

public class MyRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

        /* String currentUser = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .filter(Authentication::isAuthenticated)
                .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
                .map(User.class::cast)
                .map(User::getUsername)
                .orElse("Unknown-User"); */

        MyRevision audit = (MyRevision) revisionEntity;
        audit.setUsername("dd");

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }

}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.xxxxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>carorderprocess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>carorderprocess</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.25.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem could be related with the different dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Please, first, remove the `spring-data-envers` dependency, unless you are querying your audit tables you do not need it. Even in that case, you can use Envers on its own to obtain that information if required.

Be aware that, as indicated in the comments of the answer from Sunit, you will need to remove the attribute `repositoryFactoryBeanClass`, it could not longer take the value `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean`. But you probably still need to include the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

Although I initially indicated that you can let Spring Boot manage your versions, due to the one of `spring-boot-starter-parent`, the framework is providing you versions of `hibernate-xxx` similar to `5.2.17.Final`.

But, as you indicated, you need to use the method `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` for querying your audit entities. As you can see in the java docs, that method was introduced in [`AuditQueryCreator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQueryCreator.html#forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges-java.lang.Class-boolean-) in version `5.3`.

As a consequence, you need to provide the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId> 
  <version>5.3.20.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

But in addition you also need to provide a compatible version of both `hibernate-entitymanager` and `hibernate-core`:

```xml
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
  <version>5.3.20.Final</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
  <version>5.3.20.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Now I am getting at startup: `org.springframework.data.repository.history.RevisionRepository.findRevision(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Number)! No property findRevision found for type Customer!`

Comment: Hi farahm. And did you have any repository in which you define `findRevision`? Also, be aware that, as indicated in the comments of the answer from Sunit an in my answer, you will need to remove the attribute repositoryFactoryBeanClass, it could not longer take the value `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean`. But you probably still need to include the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. Are you extending `RevisionRepository` in any place of your code?

Comment: No, I dont have any repository in which I define `findRevision`. About your second point, yes I only have now: `@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CarorderprocessApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {`

Comment: Yes I extend: `@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends RevisionRepository<Customer,Long,Integer>, JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {`

Comment: Ok. Please, change it. Extend instead `Repository` or `JpaRepository`, for instance. Please, can you try?

Comment: You mean: `public interface TajneedRepository extends RevisionRepository<Tajneed,Long,Integer>, Repository{` ?

Comment: No, just: `public interface TajneedRepository extends JpaRepository<Tajneed,Long,Integer>`. You do not need `RevisionRepository`

Comment: Also, you can safely remove the `@Repository` annotation from your interface. You need to indicate Spring Data where to find your repositories, using for instance the attribute `basePackages` of the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. Please, see the relevant [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html).

Comment: OK, the application is running now. But the problem is, that I need that specific version of Envers, because I want to call function `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges`, which is only available in that particular version. But when I add version to dependency, I again get the error from the beginning: `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226014/discussion-between-farahm-and-jccampanero).

Comment: farahm, I must leave now, but I exemplified in my answer how you can use Envers directly to query your audit information. I hope it helps. We can join the chat if necessary tomorrow.

Comment: OK thanks, lets do the chat tomorrow, please

Comment: I have tried your `MyRevisionRepositoryImpl`, but this solution does not provide me information what fields have been changed in each revision. Thats why I need `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges`

Comment: @farahm I was able to get my local code working with Hibernate Envers only (version 5.4.23.Final) and I was also able to use `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` to get all revision history with changes... Since comment section is small, i will try to post details in the answer

Comment: Hi @farahm. I updated my answer, if you need this method, you can change the proposed repository implementation and use `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` instead. Do you have any question? Do you want to chat?

Comment: @jccampanero Yes, lets have a chat please

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, I still have a small problem, that the second element of the query return object does not contain the information such as `id` or `timestamp`. But this information is saved in the revisions table

Comment: Hi @farahm. Sorry for the late reply. Do you mean the object at index `1` in the object array returned per every revision? It should provide you an instance of `MyEntity`. Is it not giving you that information?

Comment: Yes, it is returning instance of `MyEntity`, but `id=0, timestamp=0, username=null`. But in `revinfo` table I have the information: `id|timestamp    |username               |
--|-------------|-----------------------|
 6|1608132477781|user123|`

Comment: It is very strange, indeed, your revision entity configuration looks fine. Please, can you share the code you are using to process the revision information when you are obtaining these results?

Comment: I have shared a screenshot in the chat

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, I have asked another question related to this. Maybe you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333022/hibernate-envers-forrevisionsofentitywithchanges-only-returning-last-modified-co

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood from all the comments above, your requirement is

- to use Envers Auditing
- and use method `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` to get list of all revisions with what changed in them

Please start by doing these

- Remove dependency of `spring-data-envers` library.
- Just keep library `hibernate-envers` - version `5.4.23.Final` also worked for me
- Remove `repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class` from `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation
- All Repository classes should only extend from `JpaRespository` and NOT from `RevisionRepository`. You dont need `RevisionRepository`

You should be able to get your application up and running now.

Now coming back to the question, how to get all revisions with changes using `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` method.

- Create an AuditConfiguration class like this, to create the `AuditReader` bean

  ```
   @Configuration
   public class AuditConfiguration {

   private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

   AuditConfiguration(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   AuditReader auditReader() {
       return AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
   }
  ```

  }
- In your `AuditRevisionEntity` class, add following annotation. Without this the serialization of this class wont work. e.g

  ```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
  public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
  ```
- In your entity class add option `withModifiedFlag = true` to `@Audited` annotation. Without this you cannot get entity revisions with all changes. e.g

  ```
   @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
   public class Customer {
  ```
- Modify your database table for this entity audit table and fields *_mod. e.g if you have a `customer` table with fields `name`, `age`, `address` columns, then add columns `name_mod`, `age_mod`, `address_mod` to the `customer_audit` table
- Last, add following code in your service method to get audit revisions with changes

  ```
   @Autowired
   private AuditReader auditReader;

   public List<?> getRevisions(Long id) {
   AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
               .forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges(Customer.class, true)
           .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id));
   return auditQuery.getResultList();
  ```

  }

I will try to post the same code in Github sometime today, so that you can take a look at working code.

Comment: As soon as I specify the version for `hibernate-envers` in pom.xml, I start getting the error again (the one mentioned in the question)

Comment: @farahm I tried with both (specifying and not specifying versions for enver). If i didn't specify the version, then  with `Spring Boot Version 2.2.3`, gradle was pulling 
 `envers 5.4.10.Final`. However now I have upgraded to `Spring Boot 2.4.1` and now gradle is pulling `envers 5.4.25.Final`.

Comment: You can try the code without specifying `hibernate-envers` version too.
If it still does not work, you can compare with the code that I have working currently and see if there is any mismatch between our codes that is causing the issue. I have checked in my code at - https://github.com/chatterjeesunit/spring-boot-app/tree/v4.0 (checkout `tag v4.0`)

Comment: Hi Sunit. jccampanero has found out the problem as you can see in his answer. I also needed specific `hibernate-entitymanager` and `hibernate-core` dependencies in pom

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. But it may not be sufficient to identify the root cause.

Looking at the exception it is clear that application is failing since it is not able to find bean dependency

Could you try following

1. Check your library imports first in your build.gradle or pom.xml. Generally you should not require any other Hibernate library other than Spring Boot Data JPA and Hibernate Envers
2. Try removing/disabling the Hibernate Envers audit code and library dependencies and see if can you get your application up and running. This will help you identify if error is due to Hibernate Envers or if your application code has other issues.

If above does not works, then please provide more information

1. Which version of Spring Boot are you on
2. What libraries have you imported (build.gradle or maven pom file)
3. What other Configurations you have in your project - do you have any other JPA configuration file or any other custom configuration related to Hibernate or JPA
4. What annotations are on the main application class
5. Directory structure of your Repository class, and the directory on which you do component scan (in case you have overridden it)

Comment: The stuff after "If above does not works, then please provide more information" is suited in a comment. You just need 1 rep to start commenting! :)

Comment: Yes when I remove `MyRevision` and `MyRevisionListener ` the application runs correctly. I have attached pom.xml file to question

Comment: Update: After removing`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>`


I get error with: `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class CarorderprocessApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {`

Comment: @farahm 
1. You should not need `spring-data-envers` library. Hibernate Envers (`hibernate-envers`) is enough for you to get started with Hibernate envers auditing.
2. Also once you remove `spring-data-envers`, you may need to remove this from `@EnableJpaRepositories`  - `repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class` (since this class is present within the spring data envers - `org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support`

Comment: Try removing both Spring Data Envers library and also the `repositoryFactoryBeanClass` configuration inside `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know

Comment: @farahm Are you still getting the original error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry` OR are you now getting different error now?

Comment: @SunitChatterjee I have added a bounty on this question, if you can help further...