# Same site cookie issue in spring boot in vue js app

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

My tech-stack is SpringBoot + VueJS and I'm having an issue in Safari browser during login. Using Spring Security on server-side and authentication is session based. Safari is blocking the third-party cookies which is preventing the session to be made on it hence I'm unable to use my application on Safari browser.

Comment: Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324724/safari-set-cookies-not-working-for-first-party-cookie/66448703#66448703) related SO question, I think it can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need cookie access as third-party, use the Storage Access API.

Source -> https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/