# iOS safari ignores auth cookie

Tags: ios, spring-boot, cookies, safari

My Angular app with Springboot backend uses JSESSIONID Cookie for authenticating API calls. The cookie set by the backend are ignored on iOS 16 and hence API calls are not working. This works on Safari when 'Cross Site Tracking' is allowed.

This seems to be a very common problem reported in a lot of places with lot of solutions. But I am unable to find a concrete solution that works for me. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/680039)  [AndHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324724/safari-set-cookies-not-working-for-first-party-cookie)  [HereToo](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/04/safari-third-party-cookies-block/)

Solutions like SameSite(None,Lax), CookiePath(removed), DomainName/Pattern havent helped. My cookie serializer looks like below:

```
@Bean
CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() 
{
    DefaultCookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
    defaultCookieSerializer.setCookiePath("/");
    defaultCookieSerializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);
    defaultCookieSerializer.setSameSite("None");
    defaultCookieSerializer.setDomainNamePattern("aws.comp.com$");
    return defaultCookieSerializer;
}
```

Deployment on: AWS Cloudfront & API Gateway